# Set HTML Input invalid on server

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I'm using HTML5 form validation to validate my form. So if I validate it using Javascript, I can do something like that:

```
if (isInvalid())
{
    myControl.setCustomValidity("my error message");
}
```

And it's working fine. My doubt is about server-side validation. The form is posted back to the same page, and if an error is detected, the input control should be considered invalid from the start, something like that:

```
<input type="text" name="id" invalid error-message="This id is already used" />
```

I don't want to use AJAX to make this validation, because I would have to 'hijack' and cancel the form submit, make the validation using AJAX, and then submit the form in javascript.

Comment: If you don't use AJAX, then the page reloads when you submit the form. The server side script can add attributes to the input to mark it invalid.

Comment: And what i need to known is wich attributes are theese.

Comment: lots of validation JS libraries provide server-side validation functionality as well.

Comment: I don't think there's a standard attribute that just makes the input invalid.

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to iterate over context

1. You are not using AJAX and are sending form over http page load
2. One thing to keep in mind is either ways AJAX or otherwise form will only follow course on clicking of submit button. Hence the name form submission.
3. With in the form we have a field which may be valid or invalid.
4. If the field is invalid then run error which seems to work or if field is valid then simply glide through to next step in form submission.
5. On server side detect if field is invalid or not .... and do what ever is dependant on the context.

Issue on server side is it has nothing to do, nor controls and nor wants to control UI, html display in your browser.
All it handles is request i.e. GET, POST, PUT, HEAD etc and responds accordingly.

1. Browser sends page request to web server - it may pack form data or it may not pack form data dependant on the context.
2. Web server fetches the page and forwards if there is any packed form data with the request to the page and there is always lot more data getting passed around other then just form e.g. cookies, User agents, IPs etc
3. once the page is loaded into process stream you little bit of programming tells it to find form data if there is any and processes that for data to make a response out put.

So we are having a conflict of interest between point no 4 and point no 5.

- Thing is your form  is ultimately just a payload for HTTP (which is just a payload for tcp in turn and so on).
- HTTP inherently does not and should not identify data types in payload, it is just an array for HTTP. KEYWORD FOCUS array.
- You can select how to represent data in the array

It may look something like this
GET /?say=Hi&to=Mom HTTP/2.0
Host: foo.com

read more here [how forms are sent to webserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data)

So bottom line forms are only going in some form of array format, we know arrays always have key value pair e.g. ['say' => 'hi'] there is key and there is value.

usually java-script does not offer out of the box key value pairing for arrays it has values and uses their index as key e.g. ['hi', 'there'] behind the scene is equivalent to in some hackyway to [0 => 'hi', 1 => 'there'] just keep that in mind java script does not offer multidimensional arrays out of the box.
so how does java script handle arrays or how we define it  we it goes like this
var say = ['hi'];

now you may see whats happening around say=Hi in form data. There is massive array of Get with in which are key value pairs separated by &
for php sake it looks something like this

```
$_GET = [
'say' => 'hi',
'to' => 'mom']
```

we detect in page through $_GET['say'] which returns the value against it.
This is universal and will remain this for a long time to come.

What you are trying to do it attempting to detect on server from form data wither any of the key value pair has valid value or not.

Well reason why url sending is so fast it happens in less then 2 seconds gone from one part of the planet to another. While response as in downloading the web-page is so slow because inherently do not send html code through url request as show in example above. they send militaristic information understood universally.

This in turn means since there is html going to server then sever cannot detect any attributes they only have key value pair. So out attribute detection is out of window. Through error and trials we developers get the hang of this explicit revelation.

Anyways so how do we deal with this;

- Some make cookies some make extra hidden fields
- Then trigger on submit event on form to do the magic they need to do
- some even run server side validation by running validation function on server e.g.

  ```
   if($_GET['say' != 'hi'){do this thing something} else { do that thing}
  ```

Trust me there are always some kind of function or loop run on server side to make validation. WE have not found default validation way as of yet.

So we use form on submit event

```
document.getElementById('myform').onsubmit = function() {
 var cheking = document.getElementById('myfield').value;
    if(cheking != 'what ever you want'){ 
        alert('fail!'); 
        return false; // prevent the form to submit
    }
}
```

This is the general idea dont submit form which is half crooked but incase it does need be sent then slight change of code

```
 document.getElementById('myform').onsubmit = function() {
     var cheking = document.getElementById('myfield');
        if(cheking.value != 'what ever you want'){ 
cheking.value = 'invalid';            
alert('fail!'); 
        }
    }
```

form will submit and on server side for that key we will have value as invalid so php side would be

```
    if($_GET['myfield' = 'invalid'){stop processing or whatever else } else { keep on processing}
```

Because this had been going on for so and so and so long it became a standard of its own through input pattern attribute which takes care of all of the above on client side and is pretty much what you have done.

[input pattren](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_input_pattern.asp)

[bunch of regex to help you along](https://www.html5pattern.com)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The input pattern attribute</h1>

<form action="">
  <label for="country_code">Country code:</label>
  <input type="text" id="country_code" name="country_code" pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}" required oninvalid="runvalidity(this)" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')"

  title="Three letter country code"><br><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>


<script>
function runvalidity(ele){

ele.setCustomValidity('Enter country name please');
ele.value = "invalid";

}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

we created a pattern which on on submit event will manage and wont send form the in JavaScript we have run bunch of events on input field where we call custom function which makes UI as you wanted and alters the input value. if for any reason form does go through with invalid value we can then run server side validation as shown above using the same logic.

nevertheless browser will only send count_name=invalid or country_name=usa etc

Hope gist helps you understand whats behind the scene. my suggestion will be develop a UI context then fit in code logic (key word logic) matching both on client and server side.

I personally use pasterns and filet through same conditions on server side. some time client side logic can be tightened up so much there is lesser need to compare on server side. Again it depends how one fits in their code logic.